# Estimating the bias of a coin

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, estimation

Imagine we toss a coin 10 times and we get 6 heads.

How would we go about:

1. Estimating the bias of the coin
2. Uncertainty of the result

These were actually interview questions. I thought I could start by using Bayes theorem assuming that the coin being biased had a probability 'p'... but that wasn't really taking me anywhere...

How should I go about solving these questions?

Comment: [Hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) is what you're after.

Comment: why downvoting this question? Point 2 is not trivial (or maybe it is, but not for me) and I couldn't find an answer anyway.

Comment: E[B] = (h+1) / (h+t+2) See https://heliosphan.org/estimating-biased-coin.html for the full derivation. I'm not sure about the second question regarding uncertainty, but would be interested to understand more and maybe extend my post, if anyone has any thoughts/info on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Bayesian approach, you will want a [prior distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) for the probability $p$ of heads.   With a Bernouilli or binomial random variable, the [conjugate family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) (whose main merit is that it is easiest to work with) is the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Seeing $h$ heads and $t$ tails, i.e. a likelihood proportional to $p^h(1-p)^t$, will give a posterior distribution for $p$ which is also a Beta distribution but with parameters $\alpha+h$ and $\beta+t$.  This posterior distribution will have a mean of $\dfrac{\alpha+h}{\alpha+h+\beta+t}$, a mode of $\dfrac{\alpha+h-1}{\alpha+h+\beta+t-2}$, and a standard deviation of $\sqrt{\dfrac{(\alpha+h)(\beta+t)}{(\alpha+h+\beta+t)^2(\alpha+h+\beta+t+1)}}$

Common choices for the prior are $\alpha=\beta=1$ (a uniform prior), $\alpha=\beta=0$ (an improper Haldane prior), and $\alpha=\beta=\frac12$ (a Jeffreys prior)

For example, starting with $\alpha=\beta=\frac12$ and your observation of $h=6,t=4$ would give a posterior distribution for $p$ with mean about $0.59$, mode about $0.61$ (compare these to the naive estimate of $\frac6{10}=0.6$) and standard deviation about $0.14$

Comment: Isn't the posterior mean ~0.58, not 0.59? (7/12=0.5833...)

Comment: @MichaelMior that depends on whether you use a prior with $\alpha=\beta=\frac12$  or $\alpha=\beta=1$

Comment: Whoops. I clearly misread which prior you were using. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

The more times you repeat the experiment the better the estimate of the true probability. This is the Strong Law of Large Numbers https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers